# UITableView gets Slower with every new NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a UITableView that populates the results of a search that the user looks up. In order to do this I am using a NSMutableArray of Dictionaries where objects are added for the first 10, and then when the user scrolls to the bottom it populates the next 10 until there are no results left to show.

This all works well and good but I started to notice that the more searches that are done, the slower the table gets. Here is some of the code:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.objectsArray removeAllObjects];
    [self.objectsArray setArray:nil];
    [itemsTable reloadData];
    [itemsTable scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) animated:false];

    [self loadItemsFromURL:searchURL withItemDescription:encodedString atStartRow:start andEndRow:end];
}
```

The above is when a new search is performed. It then does a NSURLConnection and responds with this:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (self.objectsArray == nil)
        self.objectsArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
        // self.objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *returnArray = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:itemsData options:kNilOptions error:&error] valueForKey:@"items"];
    for (id key in returnArray)
    {
        [self.objectsArray addObject:[returnArray objectForKey:key]];
    }
    counter += 10;
    [itemsTable reloadData];
}
```

As you can see, if a user conducts a new search all objects are removed with `[self.objectsArray removeAllObjects]`and I even try to set the array to `nil`. If I perform multiple searches the `UITableView` gets slower and slower with scrolling each time. It is  almost like the controller sees the array as getting larger and larger with each search even though I am removing all of the objects from it before the search. Any ideas or am I going about this the wrong way?

**EDIT:**
Here is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. `cell` is a subclassed `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Product Cell";
    static NSString *LoadCellIdentifier = @"Loading Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if ([self.objectsArray count] <= 0 )
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.itemName.text = @"No items found.";
        cell.itemPrice.text = @"";
        cell.itemLocation.text = @"";
        cell.addButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([indexPath row] == [self.objectsArray count])
        {
            if ( [self.objectsArray count] >= 10 )
            {
                if ( [self.objectsArray count] < counter)
                {
                    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadCellIdentifier];
                    [cell.loadingSpinner stopAnimating];
                    cell.itemName.text = @"No more items found.";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!running)
                    {
                        [self loadItemsFromURL:searchURL withItemDescription:encodedString atStartRow:[self.objectsArray count] + 1 andEndRow:[self.objectsArray count] + 10];
                        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadCellIdentifier];
                        cell.itemName.text = @"Loading more items...";
                        [cell.loadingSpinner startAnimating];
                        running = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadCellIdentifier];
                        [cell.loadingSpinner startAnimating];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            NSArray *match = [self.objectsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            cell.addButton.hidden = NO;
            if ([match valueForKey:@"DESCRIPTION"] == [NSNull null] )
            {
                cell.itemName.text = @"Description not available.";
            }
            else
            {
                cell.itemName.text = [match valueForKey:@"DESCRIPTION"];
            }
            if ([match valueForKey:@"AD"] != [NSNull null])
            {
                NSMutableString *adString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[match valueForKey:@"AD"]];
                NSRange textRange;
                textRange = [adString rangeOfString:@"1/"];
                if (textRange.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    [adString replaceCharactersInRange:[adString rangeOfString:@"1/"] withString:@"$"];
                }
                else
                {
                    [adString replaceCharactersInRange:[adString rangeOfString:@"/"] withString:@"/$"];
                }
                cell.itemPrice.text = adString;
            }
            else if ([match valueForKey:@"REGULAR"] == [NSNull null])
            {
                cell.itemPrice.text = @"$ N/A";
            }
            else
            {
                NSNumberFormatter *currencyStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
                [currencyStyle setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
                [currencyStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
                NSNumber *price = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[match valueForKey:@"REGULAR"] doubleValue]];
                NSString *stringPrice = [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:price];
                cell.itemPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringPrice];
            }
            if ([match valueForKey:@"AISLE"] == [NSNull null])
            {
                cell.itemLocation.text = @"Item location: N/A";
            }
            else
            {
                cell.itemLocation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item Location: %@", [match valueForKey:@"AISLE"]];
            }
            match = nil;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here is a snippet of what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    items =     {
        263149 =         {
            AD = "###";
            AISLE = 6A;
            DESCRIPTION = "Cinnamon Toasters";
            R = 9;
            REGULAR = "#.##";
        };
        26599 =         {
            AD = "####";
            AISLE = 6A;
            DESCRIPTION = "Quaker Life Cereal";
            R = 2;
            REGULAR = "#.##";
        };
        40517 =         {
            AD = "###";
            AISLE = 6A;
            DESCRIPTION = "Toasted Oats";
            R = 1;
            REGULAR = "#.##";
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: The only problem I see is that you're creating a NSArray for each object, why? Not even for each object, for each key.

Comment: Try timing your call to `loadItemsFromURL`. If it is not implemented right, it may become incrementally slower and slower.

Comment: It isn't necessarily the call that is slowing it down. When you scroll the UITableView, the more searches you do/the more items there are as an overall total that is, you can start to see a stutter in the UI of the scrolling like it is trying to read a very large array.

Comment: @8vius I am not sure why was allocating another array there. I am doing this for each key because each key contains an entire dictionary within it. so: items => { 123456 => { key => value, key => value, key => value}, 123457 =>{...}, and so on. The key I am looking at in this case would be 123456, 123457,... I removed the nsarray allocation but it still has the stutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think your problem is the excessive creation of Array objects. So do the following instead of you're array creation:

```
NSDictionary *returnArray = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:itemsData options:kNilOptions error:&error] valueForKey:@"items"];
for (NSDictionary *dict in returnArray in returnArray)
{
    [self.objectsArray addObject:dict];
}
counter += 10;
[itemsTable reloadData];
```

What you'll get as you see is an array of `NSDictionary` objects, your return array is already an `NSDictionary` of dictionary objects. Also, slight observation, where are you resetting your counter?

**EDIT:** creating the `NSDictionary` from `NSData`:

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.requestData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error]
```

The requestData is generated using these delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  NSLog(@"In didReceiveResponse");
  [self.requestData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  NSLog(@"In didReceiveData");
  [self.requestData appendData:data];
}
```

Comment: That will give me an access error if I do that as I am looking a the next level identifier (aka: key). The counter is being reset in the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` function, I just removed it from the code block since it doesn't apply to the problem area. I did change the code per your previous suggestion however and I tried this in the same fashion that would make it work and the issue remained. From what I see it simply is not releasing the `NSMutableArray` of `objectsArray` like i think it should. Only other thing I could think it would be is the TableViewCell??

Comment: What gives you an access error? Pulling the data out like I said? It doesn't clear out the array?

Comment: I changed my code above so you can see what I mean. if I use your suggestion in this answer I would have to do `[self.objectsArray addObject:[returnArray valueForKey:dict]]` to get to the inner most dictionary.

Comment: Odd, I've done this several times and it treats the NSDictionary that I get from the JSON Serialization properly, it's a large dictionary with several sub-dictionary and I iterate over them this way, without having to do what you say.

Comment: Well there is a slight difference in what I do, I generate the NSDictionary from data and not from an array, I'll reflect it in my answer.

Comment: I will have to try this other method that you have added. I am doing this in a similar matter with appending the data but the JSONSerialization is different. When I run it through instruments i can see the memory allocation climb every time i perform a new search. This resides in a `UITabController` so even when I switch screens the `objectsArray` does not release and the memory allocation in instruments doesn't change. Since I am using ARC I can't exactly `dealloc` the array unless I change the entire file.

Comment: It doesn't release or it doesn't get cleared? Because your line for creating a new NSArray will only run once, when you load your view, because after that it will never be nil.

Comment: When i perform a search I remove all objects and set the array to nil. I checked to make sure that it does validate as nil and it does. When I look at the memory allocations I should see it drop (in instruments) when I set the MutableArray to nil correct? I don't and the more times I perform the search, the slower the UI seems to get. The count is correct but the allocation seems to just grow. It starts to effect UI once it hits about 200+ array dictionary objects.

Comment: The only thing I'm seeing is that in your cellForRowAtIndex path depending on what happens you are allocating a lot of objects. And this if: [indexPath row] == [self.objectsArray count] will never happen. Rows start to count at 0 and the count will always be last row + 1. You gotta try and simplify your method a little.

Comment: I will see what I can do about the allocations in the cellForRow method. When I am setting the `numberOfRowsInSection` I am actually checking the count and adding a row to it there. I would have to send you the entire file for it to make sense. The logic works, I just have a leak somewhere that I can't seem to find. The code is about a year old and was originally written when I was still learning.

Comment: I see, well use all the knowledge you have now to clean it up a little :) that will probably reveal your problem more clearly, sorry I can't be of any more help with the current information. still let me know if you make any progress.

Comment: I was able to find the issue and posted it as an answer below but you were essentially right since it did come down to allocations so I gave you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the issue in one line in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I commented out: `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` at the top and made sure it was only called once. I also did do a bit of cleanup as suggested by 8vius and now only once NSString is being allocated in that method call. Once I did these two things it was nice and responsive again without any stutters.